# Selenium IDE: How to count the number of lines in a text area?

Tags: selenium, count, ide, textarea

I have this textarea where anyone can type/paste in multiple phonenumbers, with only one phone number entered per line. When this is saved, the numbers will then appear in a table listing all phone numbers for that user.

I am trying to create a test where I can count the number of phonenumbers that the user entered. I will use this number to compare the total number of phonenumbers before and after the user added them in the textarea

For example a user might type in 2 phonenumbers in the textarea:

123456789

102563987

StoreCSS and xpath count won't work in this case since the characters that a user types in won't be saved in the html.

I have tried storing the value that is typed in the textarea and splitting the lines, but I'm stuck there and not sure what to do next.

Any help will be most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: What do you got by splitting the lines? Can you give the site address?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. Say for example, stackoverflow's comment area is of `textarea`. Its css is:

```
textarea[name='comment']
```

I could able to do this:

```
String commentText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[name='comment']")).getText()
```

Then you can split the string using `\n`, like this:

```
commentText.split("\n").size()
```

is giving me the number of lines entered by the user.

Comment: can i use this in IDE? or is this for webddriver only?

Comment: Not sure about that, you can give it a try.

Comment: tried, seems i can't use it. :( thanks anyway though